# update package.json file after Upgrade from @angular/cli 1.4.4 to 1.4.7

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am working on an angular project created using **@angular/cli 1.4.4**. Now I have upgraded my **@angular/cli to 1.4.7** . Now I am wondering , how should I be updating my project's **package.json** file. I did not find a decent way on the web so I just created an new test project using **@angular/cli 1.4.7** and than used it's package.json file in the existing project.  Do we have a decent/official way of upgrading package.json file after updating **@angular/cli version ??**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apparently, you are still a beginner and what you should understand is that `@angular/cli` is a simple npm package as any other package you install from npm so after you update your angular cli globally:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

simply run the following commands to update the @angular/cli package locally in your project:

```
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli
```

**Edit:**

angular cli does not offer a way to update your npm packages associated with your project so your best bet is to install a tool like [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) which will check and update your outdated dependencies in your package.json file including @angular/cli package.

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
```

Comment: Let me explaine my question. every version of @angular/cli has a specific **package.json** file associated with it as part of boiler plate code. you probably know that package.json file changes with each upgrade of @angular/cli (  for example Rxjs version updated to 5.x and so on).  So I was asking in that regard. Hope it clarifies my question.

Comment: @Akash ok got you! I updated my answer hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

To update all the outdated packages in your `package.json`file, use
`npm-check -u` this will let you update your packages interactively in the terminal. It's the best way I've found to do something like this.